# Infinitesimal generator in context of SDEs

Tags: derivatives, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the following SDE: $$X(t)= s + \int_{t_0}^t b(X(s)) dt + \int_{t_0}^t a(X(s)) dW(t) $$

where $X(t_0)=s$ and $a:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d \times N} $,$b:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d $ and $W$ denoting an $N$ dimensional Brownian Motion.

The infinitesimal generator is defined then as $$L[u](x) = b(x) D_x u(x) + \frac{1}{2} tr[a(x)a(x)^T D^2_x u(x)]$$

I do not understand why in this formula the mixed second derivatives will not be considered, meaning something like $\partial_{x_i x_j}$ for $i \ne j $

An application of  Itos-formula on $du(X(t)))$ yields $$du(X(t))) = L[u](X(t))dt + D_x u(X(t)) a(x) dW(t)$$

Why do I not need the mixed second derivatives in this formula matching with the defintion of the infinitesimal generator?

Comment: Here is some intuition behind it.  (The part you wrote is continued by $dt$, this is brought by either $dt$ itself or $dW(t) \times dW(t)$, with some notional abuse). In other words only quadratic variation is considered to yield to $dt$, while mixed variations do not, as multivariate Brownian motion (in most of the literature) is consider to have independent components.  (I know the last sentence makes it all, so sorry for long text).

Comment: I see. Thank you. Since $<W^i, W^j> =   t1_{\{i=j\}}$ I only need the derivatives on the diagonal of the hessian  matrix.

Comment: Exactly ( again with little bit abuse of notion again, (Here the $I$, should be understood as something with has derivative in natural sense in $t$) ).  ))

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast and clear answer:)

Comment: Your formular above includes the Hessian $D^{2}u$, thus in particular it does include second order mixed derivatives!

Comment: @Tobsn: But I only consider the trace, so in particular the diagonal elements?.

Comment: Did I missunderstand the first formula?

Comment: It's the trace of a product of matrices. It does include non-diagonal entries of $D^{2}u$ as well.

Comment: Ok considering $a=(a_1, a_2) $ I get $\partial_{x_1x_2} a_1^2 +2\partial_{x_1x_2} a_1 a_2 + \partial_{x_2x_2} a_2^2$.

Comment: @Tobsn. I do not quite get why I need this mixed terms for $d(u(X(t))) $

Comment: In your original post you wrote you don't understand why these terms don't appear. Now you say you don't get why they appear. I'm confused.

Comment: The answers before suggest that they should not appear, because of the quadratic variation of the Brownian motion.

Comment: @Tobsn   Why do I need them here?

Comment: because $d\langle (aW)_{i},(aW)_{j}\rangle_{t}=(aa^{T})_{ij}dt$

Comment: But I thought that can only be dt if $i=j$?

Comment: @Tobsn: How do you get from the left hand side to the right side in detail?

Comment: I leave the details to you. It's as a simple but instructive exercise.

Comment: Using bilinearity I end up with: $d<a_i W_i, a_j W_j> =  a_i a_j <W_i, W_j> = a_i a_j t 1_{\{i=j\}} $

Comment: So I would get $0$ for $i \ne j$. What do I wrong?

Comment: $(aW)_{i}$ is the $i$-th component of the vector you get when multiplying $W$ with matrix $a$.